# Difference between tf.layers.conv1d vs tf.layers.conv2d

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

What is the difference in the functionalities of `tf.layers.conv1d` and `tf.layers.conv2d` in tensorflow and how to decide which one to choose?

Comment: Please add more details about the context. For obvious reasons `tf.layers.conv1d` is used for one-dimensional data and `tf.layers.conv2d` is used in two-dimensional data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`tf.layers.conv1d` is used when you slide your convolution kernels along 1 dimensions (i.e. you reuse the same weights, sliding them along 1 dimensions), whereas `tf.layers.conv2d` is used when you slide your convolution kernels along 2 dimensions (i.e. you reuse the same weights, sliding them along 2 dimensions).

So the typical use case for `tf.layers.conv2d` is if you have a 2D image. And possible use-cases for `tf.layers.conv1d` are, for example:

- Convolutions in Time
- Convolutions on Piano notes